# How to convert pdf to mp3/aiff in OSX (Chapter by Chapter)

Tags: macos, pdf, say

I am using OSX and I am looking for a tool to convert pdf to mp3. Found this article http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080427091554310 where it converts entire pdf to a single mp3. I want to break pdf into Chapters and then convert Chapters to mp3. Is there any opensource tool to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it.

But you could easily do it in two steps.

First use a tool like [PDF Split and Merge](http://www.pdfsam.org/) to split it into chapters and then use the solution you found at [hints.macworld.com](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080427091554310).